# What is Sakaki's Heian Hyakudan?

Tags: historys-strongest-disciple-kenichi

As a former Shotokan Karate practitioner myself, I am quite familiar with the Heian Kata series. However I have never heard of Heian Hyakudan before.

[image]

First and foremost, is this a real technique or kata? I've been trying to find out more about Heian Hyakudan through google searches, but I get absolutely nothing.

If we dissect his finishing stance, we might be able to come closer to a conclusion. His bottom section, leg and hip formation is a posture held after jumping or leaping. We also know he is landing from a jump due to his forward shoulder being lower than the back shoulder (as well as the visual landing effect).

The part that throws me off the most is his upper posture. Normally when a jumping technique is executed, both arms work together and are connected(katas: Heian Godan and Bassai Dai). In this picture, his left arm is back which would mean that his technique requires a certain hip motion. The only times I recall seeing the top posture is in a Kata like Chinte, but even then, the leg stance requires feet to be spread out with open or reverse hips.

The top just doesn't match with the bottom. I have never seen a technique like this, nor heard of it.

Please help me identify this specific technique or Heian Hyakudan.

Comment: Have you tried asking your sensei or shihan?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have contact with my sensei anymore. I live in a different country now :(

Comment: :o and you didn't join another dojo??? karate is not a sport or a martial art, it is a way of life. *something preachy my shihan told me* :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The technique Heian Hyakudan is non existing technique in karate.

Shio Sakaki claims to hold 100 dan in the arts of karate . So the move Heian Hyakudan could be a word play on this with Hyaku meaning 100 (百).

As for his movements, with the rotation and forward moving speed he should have fallen indeed. Although in the manga (don't remember the exact chapters) it is also shown that Sakaki can alter his central point of gravity by using certain muscles. Which in this case would have helped him with maintaining balance and allowing him to land in such manner.

Comment: This is truly great. It slipped my mind that hyakudan was in reference to his title while I kept thinking of hyakudan as one word.

Answer (score 1):

The "Heian Hyakudan" technique pictured resembles a real technique in the kata Chatan Yara Kusanku.  I'm sure it's a coincidence but it is interesting.  You can watch a video of it [here](http://youtu.be/iiiznDpoapQ).

You will see it in the 4th and 5th directions. It has a twisted stance with a chop like this, and is followed with a kick and then a drop to the ground. I doubt if it would send multiple people flying through the air like they got hit with tornadoes, but maybe when one reaches 100th Dan...